# how to use onTouchListener in EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sqlite, ontouchlistener

i have created an application which sends two fields name and ph. no. to sqlite database. i want if i enter some name in edittext which all ready has been stored in database then phone record of that name should entered in next edtetext as i touch that edittext.  i have used onTouchListener on phone's editText. but when i run this code .  it's gives  a null pointer exeception error.
i am not getting where i use wrong code...if any on e plzz suggest me solution

code for activity class......

```
phoneeditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                Cursor c=help.getall();
                List<String>data=new ArrayList<String>();
                while(c.moveToNext()){
                    data.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                }
                String fname=name.getText().toString();
                if(data.contains(fname)){
                    help=new MyHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    Cursor c2=help.getall();
                    while(c2.moveToNext()){
                        phoneeditText.setText(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("phone")));
                    }
                    }
                    //help.update(myname, call, myarea);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myname+"already saved..it's updating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

code for SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
public Cursor getall(){
    sd=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c=sd.query("location", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
```

messages from logcat

```
07-30 03:27:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(376): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 03:27:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at com.kuldeep.localsave.Act1$1.onTouch(Act1.java:145)
07-30 03:27:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
07-30 03:27:48.567: E/AndroidRuntime(376):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
```

Comment: What line of code does the null pointer exception point to? Check the exception report for the first clickable file name that you edited. Click that file name and it should take you to the line of code that is the problem. Once you know which line, tell me.

Comment: exception raised on onTouch method

Comment: please add exception trace from logcat

Comment: i want to set phone edttext with corrosponding data from sqlite when ever i touch that edittext...

Answer (score 1):

**Take addTextChangedListener of your edittext and put your all Searching code onTextChaged Method.**

```
  phoneeditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```